# Highcharts - Is there a chart similar to full donut

Tags: highcharts

I want to show a chart that looks like a full circle donut. i have attached a screenshot. I dont see any chart with a full circle donut, so which kind of chart can i choose from the demo.

Please advice.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup there is. Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-semi-circle/). This was originally from semi circle and when you remove this  startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90, It will give you the donut.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y: 40
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                distance: -50,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },

            center: ['50%', '75%']
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        innerSize: '50%',
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   10.38],
            ['IE',       56.33],
            ['Chrome', 24.03],
            ['Safari',    4.77],
            ['Opera',     0.91],
            {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
});
```